# Angular get scss style in TS

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

i would like to know if it is possible (and how) to access a scss value as set in the scss file into the ts code of the component (maybe via a @ViewChild ?).

I want the value as in the file ("25vh" for exemple) and not the computed one.

I need this for an internal API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable in your scss file like this (at the top of the file)

```
:root {
  --myWidth: 25vh;
}
```

then use it in ur scss file

```
element {
  width: myWidth;
}
```

And u can access it in your TS file

```
//get your value
var styleProperty= element.style.getPropertyValue("--myWidth");


// set your value
element.style.setProperty("--myWidth", "50vh");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your variables in SCSS:

```
:export {
    height: $height;
    // etc...
}
```

And in ts file you can import it:

```
import variables from '{path_to_scss}'
```